# Cannot compile PuTTY, Plink or Pscp on Windows due to missing Windows/MSVC subdirectory

Tags: putty, plink, pscp

I need to download and compile plink/pscp on my Windows.
Since I need specific version (0.69), I searched for the tag, and checked out to that commit.

In putty readme, they write that if I want to compile on windows, there is Visual studio solution:

> - Inside the windows/MSVC subdirectory are MS Visual Studio project    files for doing GUI-based builds of the various PuTTY utilities.
>     These have been tested on Visual Studio 7 and 10.
>
>   You should be able to build each PuTTY utility by loading the
>     corresponding .dsp file in Visual Studio. For example,
>     MSVC/putty/putty.dsp builds PuTTY itself, MSVC/plink/plink.dsp
>     builds Plink, and so on.

I dont have these directories, What am I missing ? Is there a prerequisite ?
The code is see is as https://github.com/github/putty
That directory is missing from there also..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote response from putty staff regarding to my question:

> "From the second paragraph of that same README in the root of the Git
>   repository: "(If you have fetched the source from Git, you'll have to
>   generate the Makefiles yourself -- see below.)" That includes the
>   Visual Studio projects. Or, since you are compiling a release version,
>   you could instead download putty-0.69.tar.gz from our website, which
>   includes these generated files."

After better looking, I found the following link:

https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/releases/

Credit goes to Jacob N.

Answer (score 1):

The `MSVC` folder does not exist in the repository.

It is generated during build and stored in `putty-src.zip` package:
https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/putty-src.zip

---

*Though building an old version of a software sounds like a bad idea.*